# Better solution for sequential statement executions with PDO and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 3 tables which I have to add a record to them after registration of a new user:

*List of Tables:*

I. **users**

... ... ... id (auto_increment, primary)

... ... ... email (email address of new user)

II. **blogs**

... ... ... id (auto_increment, primary)

... ... ... owner_id (= 'id' in 'users')

III. **events**

... ... ... id (auto_increment, primary)

... ... ... owner_id (= 'id' in 'users')

... ... ... blog_id (= 'id' in 'blogs')

In this situation I found 2 solutions for adding sequential records:

**Solution 1:** Using `lastInsertId`

```
<?php 
try {
    // Step 1: add a record to 'users' table and get lastInsertId
    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (:email)");
    $query->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $query->execute();
    $user_id = $conn->lastInsertId();

    // Step 2: add a record to 'blogs' table and get lastInsertId
    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO blogs (owner_id) VALUES (:owner)");
    $query->bindParam(':owner', $user_id);
    $query->execute();
    $blog_id = $conn->lastInsertId();

    // Step 3: add a record to 'events' table
    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO events (owner_id, blog_id) VALUES (:owner, :blog)");
    $query->bindParam(':owner', $user_id);
    $query->bindParam(':blog', $blog_id);
    $query->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

**Solution 2:** Using single `execute()`

```
<?php 
try {
    // Step 1
    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (:email);" . 
                            "INSERT INTO blogs (owner_id) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = :email));" .
                            "INSERT INTO events (owner_id, blog_id) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = :email), (SELECT id FROM blogs WHERE owner_id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = :email)));");
    $query->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $query->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Which solution should I choose for a better **performance** and **security**? Is there a better solution for my purpose?

---

*Note:* the connection created using `PDO`:

```
<?php
$options = array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
);

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . App::DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . App::DB_NAME . ";charset=utf8", App::DB_USERNAME, App::DB_PASSWORD, $options);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: If event is per blog, there's no need for the user_id to be in there (because it's already in the blog's table). If the event is per user per blog, disregard this comment.

Comment: @SecondRikudo - Thanks, As you know the real project is a little different from this simplified example. So please ignore this issue

Answer (score 3):

I would use transactions as a modification of 1st option.

```
$conn->beginTransaction();

try {
    // Step 1: add a record to 'users' table and get lastInsertId
    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (:email)");
    $query->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $query->execute();
    $user_id = $conn->lastInsertId();

    // Step 2: add a record to 'blogs' table and get lastInsertId
    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO blogs (owner_id) VALUES (:owner)");
    $query->bindParam(':owner', $user_id);
    $query->execute();
    $blog_id = $conn->lastInsertId();

    // Step 3: add a record to 'events' table
    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO events (owner_id, blog_id) VALUES (:owner, :blog)");
    $query->bindParam(':owner', $user_id);
    $query->bindParam(':blog', $blog_id);
    $query->execute();

    $conn->commit();

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    // roll back transaction
    $conn->rollback();
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Comment: @yaa110 if third query fails, you will have an entry but no event. Not sure if it fits your logic, but usually for the batch insert you want either all inserted or none - whic impossible with autocommit

Comment: @YourCommonSense I see this try/catch can be avoided, and I don't doubt you are right, but I would appreciate if you could point me to why its insecure?

Comment: Displaying *any* site internal info to the visitor is a *very basic* security flaw.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - I'll set `display_errors` to `off`,However, How could I roll back all changes to the database (after any failed step) by removing try..catch?

Comment: err what? `"I'll set display_errors"` - and so what? How would it affect your code?

Comment: `How could I roll back all changes` you don't need to do that. Just leave it as is. This is how transactions work, actually. You need only commit explicitly, while rollback is not necessary

Comment: @YourCommonSense `"I'll set display_errors"`, I meant I will use `ini_set('display_errors','on');` for the final release to hide `any site internal info to the visitor`

Comment: how come? care to try your code and see if any ini_set will affect it? (assuming `off`)

Comment: @YourCommonSense my question was how try/catch itself is insecure. Of course I didn't mean OP will use echo $e->getMessage(); in catch block he can log error there or whatever. I agree try/catch is not needed, but my question is, is it insecure itself and how? Thank you.

Comment: it is not  try/catch insecure in general, but the way you are using it. That's why I asked you to remove it. The rest is your speculations. For some reason you wrote BAD code, then refuse to delete it and then you say "I didn't mean the op will use it". Why bother writing it then?

Comment: My intention was to suggest using transactions in modification to OPs first option. The way OP use error logging is not part of the question, so I could even just wrote comment //DO WHATEVER WITH YOUR ERROR HERE. OK, you disagree with code, no problem, I still appreciate your comment, next time when answering question I'll try to be more accurate. Thanks.

Comment: @Dexa - Why didn't you use option 2? what's wrong with option 2?

Answer (score 0):

Edit. I misread the question at first, thought you are using exec(), not execute().

So, in fact you can combine both, as lastInsertId is just a PHP wrapper for Mysql's LAST_INSERT_ID()
But, as you need two ids, it will require additional mess with setting a variable. So, I doubt second option would worth, although feasible.
Just note that second would work only if PDO emulation mode is turned off

And surely there is no such question like "performance". Both will go perfectly.

Comment: Thank you, just for improving my knowledge: What's wrong with solution 2?

Comment: Not all PHP users are that misinformed. Try to avoid "subtle" hints and generalization in your answer..

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Trust me, I have. Not all PHP users are that misinformed. Try to avoid "subtle" hints and generalization in your answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: You made me doubt the way I concluded from Dexa's and your previous answer. I decided to use option 1 but now after editing your answer I couldn't decide to use which one. Also, I found there is no security issue with option 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you do some benchmarks you will see most time will be lost making the request.
From personal benchmarks on simple queries like this the execution time is very low.
The only thing that realy took time is the initialisation/prepare function.

There for making 3 requests will be slower then creating one large one.

EDIT:

Option 1 is the correct one because you do need to use id's, never link using a string or somethign else allways use id's.

Appart from that 1 (prepared) big query is better then 3x a prepare.